# Does a larger number limit on Arc4random slows down loading speed?

Tags: swift, arc4random

Hi I'm new to programming here and I am curious if a larger limit number generator cause it to be slower when generating a random number? For example:

which one generates a random number faster?

```
arc4random_uniform(1000000)
```

or

```
arc4random_uniform(10)
```

Could it be the same speed?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you talking about `arc4random_uniform`? `arc4random` does not take a limit as far as I can remember

Comment: opps yes i meant that. I'll update my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your are talking about `arc4random_uniform` instead of `arc4random` since the later does not have an upper bound you can specify.

The answer is: **it might**!

---

Looking at the [source and documentation](http://opensource.apple.com//source/OpenSSH/OpenSSH-166/openssh/openbsd-compat/bsd-arc4random.c):

> Uniformity is achieved by generating new random numbers until the one
>    returned is outside the range `[0, 2**32 % upper_bound)`.  This
>    guarantees the selected random number will be inside
>    `[2**32 % upper_bound, 2**32)` which maps back to [0, upper_bound)
>    after reduction modulo upper_bound.

That means that the speed of the random number generation depends on the ratio between the upper limit of `arc4random` and the afore mentioned modulo remainder.

In your example:

`2^32 % 10 = 4`
`2^32 % 1000000 = 967.296`

Creating a random number using `arc4random()` one time yields for example `768.649` which is smaller than the second value. That means it would have to create a second random number calling `arc4random()` a second time for the later case - the first case is already done creating random numbers.

But that runtime difference is entirely up to chance.

A second program run *might* yield `1.316.166.055` on the first try which causes both calls to take the same amount of time.

Since `arc4random` is uniformly distributed the probability of the second one taking longer is somewhat close to `967.296 / 2^32` which is `0.00022521615` => in `~0.02%` of the calls the second one takes longer than the first one.

In this calculation I ignored the fact that theoretically the `arc4random` can even produce a number smaller than `4` which would trigger even the first call to requery). But it should still give you an understanding of how improbable a difference will be.

If you want to get the probably "slowest" call you would have to perform `arc4random_uniform(2^31+1)` which has a ~50% chance of failing on the first call to `arc4random`.

Comment: Wow, this is a perfect explanation! I couldn't understand that specific apple documentation but your examples made it much more easy to understand. Thanks!